# How to update scss file variable form ts file in angular 7

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have a one global variables file of SCSS and in another scss file, I am using those global variables. So I want to update global variables value from my component ts file. I included stackblitz URL.
So can anyone help me with this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-theme

My current values of

```
$primaryColor: #9C27B0;
$secondaryColor: #E91E63;
$thirdColor: #2196F3;
```

and I want these values updated like:

```
$primaryColor: #00BCD4;
$secondaryColor: #CDDC39;
$thirdColor: #795548;
```

Comment: You can't update SCSS variables via typescript

Comment: You can't. Use `ngStyle` instead.